Dask - How to optimize the computation of the first row of each partition in a dask dataframe?
My overall goal is to read several csv files, do some computation, save them as a parquet database using the partition_on option in the to_parquet function.
I cannot reindex and repartition before saving because of limited memory. When saving, each file will end up being a different partition, and thus a different parquet file. I cannot use the default file name part.0.parquet because I might need to add files to the same directory in the future and they might be as well a part.0.parquet.
I thus want to assign to each parquet file the name of the original csv file it comes from.
To do this, when I first read the csv file I add a column with the file name (--> all rows in each partition will have the same file name). Then I read the first row of each partition (and specifically the column with the original csv file name) and create a list of file names. Then I use the option name_function in the to_parquet function.
I achieve what I wanted, but in this way I have to call a .compute() and this takes very long.
Do you have any idea how I can limit the computation to the first row of each partition?
This is my current code:
def get_first_element(partition):
    return partition['orig_file_name'].iloc[0]

first_elements = ddf.map_partitions(get_first_element).compute()

def name_function(part_idx):
    return f"{first_elements[part_idx]}.parquet"    

ddf.to_parquet(path=target_directory,
               engine='pyarrow',
               partition_on=['date', 'hour'],
               name_function=name_function,
               write_index=True)

Thank you very much in advance for any suggestion!
Edit
This code replicates my problem following @mdurant suggestion:
@dask.delayed
def process(file_path):
    df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[0, 1, 2, 3], 'col2':[4, 5, 6, 7], 'col3':[88, 88, 99, 99]}) # this is read_csv in my code
    file_name = 'aaa'

    df.to_parquet(f'{file_name}.parquet',
             partition_cols=['col3'])

dask.compute(*[process(f) for f in [1]])


Are you aware of the include_path_column argument in dask.dataframe.read_csv?

Thanks for the comment, I overlooked this option. However, the main issue remains :)

"This code replicates my problem" - I see a bunch of files under aaa.parquet; what did you want to happen?

I would like to have a structure of this type:
->./col3=88/aaa.parquet
->./col3=99/aaa.parquet
in my code 'aaa' will be the original file name, and col3 will be 'hour' and 'date' structure

Right, but this is a simple rename - you can put it inside the process() function if you like

Sorry, I don't understand. Probably I am not explaining the problem correctly.
With your suggestion I cannot control the name of each single parquet file, with the code I added to my question I get files with this name: f426ef9091f244bf80be82eaff84a973-0.parquet

Yes, but they are isolated by the top-level name, so finding all the files for a given input filename is easy

Yes, but this is not what I am trying to achieve. My initial code with partition_on=['date', 'hour', 'file_name'] would have done the same. But this creates many useless levels.

If each input partition is being outputted separately (which is what I guess from your description), then you are not really using dask.dataframe's API - you could just use delayed instead.
@dask.delayed
def process(filename):
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, ...)
    ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartition=1)

    # processing

    def name(part_idx):
        f"{filename}.parquet"


    out = ddf.to_parquet(f"out.parquet", partition_cols=["date", "hour"], name_function=name, append=True, compute=False)
    dask.compute(out, scheduler="sync")

dask.compute(*[process(f) for f in filenames])


Thanks for your suggestion! However, I don't get the expected result. I add a code example in the question.

Have a try of this one

Yes, thanks! Avoiding the nested functions and saving each file directly was the solution I couldn't see :)
However, I think the function name wants part_idx as argument and not fn

OK, then maybe you need a lambda; please edit my code to something that worked for you

Now you have a closure to use the local filename of each task. I don't know if you actually have multiple partitions in each date/hour group; if yes, then you need to make use of part_idx too.
